# WebGL Hardware Acceleration - failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat no longer working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

Previously I was able to detect whether or not the browser has Hardware Acceleration enabled, by using the failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat flag.

```js
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("width", "1");
        canvas.setAttribute("height", "1");
        const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        body.appendChild(canvas);
        const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", { failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat: true });
        body.removeChild(canvas);
        return !gl;
```

However, this flag no longer seems to fail and the canvas context is still created. I'm on the latest version of Chrome (101.0.4951.67) and using Windows. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently too. I have a workaround that I'm using, but no real solution:

```js
function isSwiftShaderRenderer() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    const debug_ext = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
    if (debug_ext) {
        const renderer = gl.getParameter(debug_ext.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL);
        if (renderer.indexOf('SwiftShader') >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(isSwiftShaderRenderer());
```

**Note:** this doesn't work on Firefox and `failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat` doesn't work on Firefox due to `webgl.disable-fail-if-major-performance-caveat` defaults to `true`

Comment: Thanks! I just had a look there again and the issue seems to be gone for me now... Can you still reproduce it? Maybe it was fixed.

Comment: My requirements were slightly different, where the Chrome software renderer SwiftShader actually has a WebGL rendering issue that I needed to detect for. I also noticed that the `failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat` flag doesn't always trigger on software rendering if the computer was sufficiently powerful in the CPU, though that may have been fixed.